# Could old gate valves be causing low pressure at the faucet?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, water-pressure, plumbing-fixture

We installed a new sink/faucet last year and the first faucet we had installed had super lower water pressure which we assumed was the faucet. We replaced the faucet and the pressure improved slightly but not even close to what it is in the bathroom sink right next door. Since this was my second install in a couple of weeks we left it but we just opened the place up for the summer and the pressure is horrible so we need a fix.

There are two original (1978) gate valves that are used yearly(since we winterize) and as part of the renovation in the kitchen, I added two additional ball valves under the sink for quicker access. Now as we get ready to replace the faucet again I'm wondering if the old gate valves in the basement could be contributing to the issue or we just got really unlucky and have had two bad faucets?

If it's a hint sometimes it comes out better or starts higher but then quickly drops to a very low rate.

TLDR;

- Pressure was okay before the reno(that we can remember, not 100% on this)
- Pressure in the bathroom right next door is perfect, same water line.
- We're on well if that matters
- We're on our second brand new faucet and the pressure is slightly above a dribble.
- Both hot and cold lines are the same low pressure
- The new valves under the sink are **Brass 1/2-in Push-to-Connect x 3/8-in OD Compression Quarter Turn Straight Valve**
- Old valves are 1/2" brass valves

How should I debug this before replacing another faucet? Should I just remove them and keep the new under the sink vales since I doubt I need two?

Comment: Have you checked the pressure from the well pump ?

Answer (score 2):

First thing to try is take off the faucet altogether, get a bucket by the pipe, and get someone to trn on the ball valves. No pressure there, then look further back. Good pressure there (turn it off again!) then there's something up with the new faucet.